# Include Mini Login in CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, login, ce-1.9.2.2

I am trying to include the Mini Login Form in a CMS Page in Magento 1.9.2.

**The PHP file path is:** `app/design/frontend/rwd/kellyseye/template/customer/form/mini.login.phtml`

**This is the code I have included in my CMS Page HTML Editor:**

```
<div class="home-content">
    <div class="page-title">
    <h2>Welcome to</h2>
    <h2><strong>Cashino Market</strong></h2>
</div>
<p>Exclusively built for Cashino customers; Cashino Market offers fantastic 
products and services at discounted prices.</p>

{{block type="customer/form" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"}}

<div class="home-slider">
    {{block type="banners/banners" template="banners/banners.phtml"}}
</div>
```

Does anyone know why nothing is showing up?

Link to Store: https://cashino.kellyseye.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the correct the block `type` and add permissions for the block in order to allow it to show on the frontend.

1.) Change your block type to `customer/form_login`:

```
{{block type="customer/form_login" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"}}
```

2.) Then, within the admin, navigate to **System > Permissions > Blocks**, click `Add New Block`, add `customer/form_login` to **Block Name**, ensure **Is Allowed** is set to `Yes`, and click `Save Block`.

[image]

3.) Clear Magento cache and refresh your CMS page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the natif mini-login one, you have to set this path:

```
{{block type="customer/form_login" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"}}
```

If you have used your custom module, use instead your custom module block:

```
{{block type="{block}/{blockname}" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"}}
```